# What is Equivalent of Amazon Glacier in Microsoft Azure environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, cloud

I am doing some research where I need to find the corresponding tool for archiving. So, what will be the equivalent of amazon glacier in the Azure environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent service is the [`Azure Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services). You can always explore from the site.

[`AWS to Azure services comparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/aws-professional/services)

Answer (score 8):

The Azure equivalent service to AWS S3 is [Azure Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/). S3 defines several storage classes, Glacier is one of them.

Azure Storage has the concepts of different [access tiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal). I think the [Archive tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal#archive-access-tier) is the closest match to S3 Glacier. Another option would be the [cool tier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal#cool-access-tier). Which one to choose depends on the frequency the data is accessed.